# Split and create an array with Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, split, google-bigquery, google-query-language

Starting point:

```
id  levels
    
11   A,B,C      
12   A
13   B,C
```

How to split and create an array, expected outcome:

```
id  levels
    
11   A
11   B
11   C      
12   A
13   B
13   C
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, is “levels” an actual bigquery array or does “split” in the title imply that it’s a string that needs splitting into an array? Either way, you may want to add the table schema to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use split:

```
select id,split(levels,',') as levels yourtable
```

You can also use UNNEST

```
SELECT id, levels
FROM yourtable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(levels) AS levels;
```